# Is this considered an argument?

Tags: command-line, documentation

Some binaries in Unix-Linux systems like ping or mount have a long argument. For example if we write `ping -h` in the terminal, one of the options is:

```
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64]
```

Is this long set of characters really an argument?

Comment: "This is quite nicely explained in man man:

... [-abc] any or all *arguments* within [ ] are optional."

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495669/difference-between-terms-option-argument-and-parameter

Comment: That duplicate doesn't even answer the question of what `-abc` means here. The brackets make things optional, but there's still a difference between a literal string, a concatenation of multiple optional switches, and a string that's actually a description of some value.

Comment: No, it is a list of possible arguments! However, it is only an abbreviated list, the details are in `man ping`!

Answer (score 12):

No, this is an abbreviated way of listing all the possible single-letter options: `-a`, `-A`, `-b`, etc. See [the `ping` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iputils-ping/ping.8) for details (for better results, run `man ping` on your own system — that will show the documentation for the version you have installed).

Comment: Note that getopt-based programs usually can take arguments that way, although some may be mutually exclusive, such as `-4` and `-6` in this case.